# PostgreSQL - psql: пользователь "Washington" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)

Tags: postgresql

Установил PostgresSQL. В консоли Windows ввожу команду psql и получаю приглашение к вводу пароля. Перепробовал все пароли, какие я только могу использовать - ничего не помогает.

Сначала я подумал, что нужен пароль, который я определил при установке БД. Не прошел. Увидел сообщение (в названии темы) и подумал, что раз говорит о пользователе системы Washington, то нужен пароль пользователя системы. Не прошел. Ну затем перепробовал все пароли которые приходили на ум ))

Comment: А откуда она взяла пользователя "Washington"? Сейчас проверил, по умолчанию psql предлагает использовать имя пользователя `postgres`.

Comment: спасибо..до меня дошло :) .. почему-то по умолчанию psql использовал не postgres а имя пользователя системы.. надо вводить psql -U postgres

Comment: @Yaant при установке у меня спросили только пароль. Теперь авторизуюсь так: `psql -U postgres` и ввожу пароль. Спасибо вам за подсказку с пользователем по-умолчанию

Answer (score 8, accepted):

почему-то по умолчанию psql использовал не имя заданное при инсталляции, а имя пользователя системы.. в данном случае надо явно указать имя заданное при инсталляции - psql -U yourname